# OneUi styled navigation in android java

Tags: java, android

I'm beginner in android programming and I want to know how to make an OneUi styled navigation like [in this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuP1w.png)

This is [what I made so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjcJW.png) Unfortunately, when I scroll it, it will totally collapse and I cannot get it back.

I used CoordinatorLayout with AppBarLayout and I follow some code from material.io guidelines but it did'nt work as I expected. I want the app bar to be short when scrolled and tall when it is on the top.

Here is my XML Layout Code:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="#F0F0F0"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="72dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="28dp"

            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"

                app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"

                        android:text="This is a text"
                        android:textSize="50dp"
                        />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false">



    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case. There are few things you need to change.

1. Put the content below `AppBarLayout` in `NestedScrollView` to have scrolling `layout_behavior`.
2. Put some content to mimic scrolling effect. Like textview with huge height for example.
3. Put the content you want to collapse into one `CollapsingToolbarLayout` basically things to show when it's `tall` or not collapsed.
4. Put your `MaterialToolbar` as a direct child of `AppBarLayout`

**Example code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F0F0F0"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="28dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="72dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="This is collapsing content"
                    android:textSize="32sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:title="This is MaterialToolbar" />


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="800dp"
                android:text="Hello Test" />


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Output:**

**Not collapsed:**

[image: Not collapsed]

**Collapsed:**

[image: Collapsed]